# How to zoom in on a chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, charts

I am forecasting stock prices using a regression algo.  All code is below.  Everything works fine.  I'm just trying to figure out how to zoom in on the forecasted values, in blue.  Ideally I'd like to make this a dynamic process, rather than a hard-coded process.  TIA!!

```
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime

style.use('ggplot')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df[['Adj. Open',  'Adj. High',  'Adj. Low',  'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

y = np.array(df['label'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validate.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
df['Forecast'] = np.nan

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

for i in forecast_set:
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += 86400
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)]+[i]


df['Adj. Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Checkout [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html), there is an awesome [Jupyter sandbox tutorial](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/master?filepath=tutorial%2F00%20-%20Introduction%20and%20Setup.ipynb).

Comment: I took a look at that link, and bookmarked it too.  Seems like some very interesting materiel there!  For now, is there a simple way to reset the max and min values on the x-axis?  I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment Bokeh is awesome for making interactive plots, but if you just want to change the axis settings:

```
# Modified 5th to last line of your code:
ax = df['Forecast'].plot()
# Example with made up date range.
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-04-01'))
```